# How to connect InfluxDB from java client with verifySSL as false and ssl as true

Tags: influxdb

Trying to connect InfluxDB using 
https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java

I didn't see any option for setting `ssl` as true and `verifySSL` as false. Its available in php client. Can someone help on it?

There is no proper documentation available for java client to connect influxDB hosted in AWS, where the connection will be a `https` connection.

Here is the code and exception thrown.

```
InfluxDB influxDB = InfluxDBFactory.connect(databaseURL , userName, password);
Pong response = influxDB.ping();
```

Exception Stacktrace:

```
org.influxdb.InfluxDBIOException: java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: 
    at org.influxdb.impl.InfluxDBImpl.execute(InfluxDBImpl.java:800)
    at org.influxdb.impl.InfluxDBImpl.executeQuery(InfluxDBImpl.java:783)
    at org.influxdb.impl.InfluxDBImpl.describeDatabases(InfluxDBImpl.java:709)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround.. some positive result. But, its unsecured way of communication.

```
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {               
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
          return true;
        }
   });
   InfluxDB influxDB = InfluxDBFactory.connect(databaseURL , userName, password, builder);
```